# Locale object creation issue

Tags: java, locale

I have a locale string `"fi_FI"`. When I create a new `java.util.Locale` object like this -

```
String myLocaleStr = "fi_FI";
Locale locale = new Locale(myLocaleStr);
```

-and check `locale` information value using `sysout` statement, I observe that the Locale value displayed is `"fi_fi"` and not `"fi_FI"`.

Is there any way I can retain the locale value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Locale constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale%28java.lang.String%29) you use considers the unique argument you pass is the language. Not a combination of language and country. Split the string, and use [the other constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), accepting a language and a country:

```
String[] languageAndCountry = myLocaleStr.split("_");
Locale locale = new Locale(languageAndCountry[0], languageAndCountry[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the newer versions of Java but the constructor looks like this:

`/**
     * Construct a locale from language, country, variant.
     * NOTE:  ISO 639 is not a stable standard; some of the language codes it defines
     * (specifically iw, ji, and in) have changed.  This constructor accepts both the
     * old codes (iw, ji, and in) and the new codes (he, yi, and id), but all other
     * API on Locale will return only the OLD codes.
     * @param language lowercase two-letter ISO-639 code.
     * @param country uppercase two-letter ISO-3166 code.
     * @param variant vendor and browser specific code. See class description.
     * @exception NullPointerException thrown if any argument is null.
     */
    public Locale(String language, String country, String variant) {
        this.language = convertOldISOCodes(language);
        this.country = toUpperCase(country).intern();
        this.variant = variant.intern();
    }`

Do you see that the country code will be set to uppercase. This is according to ISO standards.